# Laravel 5.1 - Override default errors variables of the default login to differentiate between two forms on the same page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 and i have a create form with a sidebar which also has a login form. Whenever i submit the create form and it has errors, i see the errors on both the login form and the create form. I understand why it's happening. I am using @include('errors.list') on both forms.

The list.php file inside errors

```
@if  ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <strong>• {{$error}}</strong><br/>
            @endforeach
        </div>
@endif
```

Now, i want to change the errors value on the login form when validation fails. I am using the default authentication form. I want to create something like 
if validation fails -> return with ('login_errors') instead of the default errors so i can use something like @if  ($login_errors->any())

2nd question would be, how would i do the reverse without using custom validation? I am using $request, if i wanted to return the errors to the create form with custom_errors.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding correctly - you want to have custom error messages? Here is the documentation Laravel provides for that: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#working-with-error-messages (scroll down a little bit). Using this, you can continue to use the same `$errors->any()` to check if any error messages exist.

Answer (score 0):

First you need some way to distinguish between the forms. The easiest way is to add a hidden field in your `<form>`, for instans like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="loginFromSidebar" value="1">
```

To be able to act on your newly created trigger you need to override the `postLogin` function in the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait by changing line 24 in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php` from

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

to

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers {
    postLogin as laravelPostLogin;
}, ThrottlesLogins;
```

This will rename the `postLogin` function that larval provides so we can use our own as a shim in front of it.
Your shim function should be named `postLogin` and should in turn call the built in function now renamed `laravelPostLogin`.

To keep track of the form used I suggest using the [session flash feature](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data) in larvel. It's perfectly fine to set this on all login attempts wether or not the login failes or not. The flash variable will only last for one page load so it will not be in the way later if the login is successful. The `postLogin` should be added somewhere in `AuthController.php` and could look like this

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('loginFromSidebar')) {
        \Session::flash('loginFromSidebar', true);
    }
    return $this->laravelPostLogin($request);
}
```

Then you can use

```
@if(Session::has('loginFromSidebar'))
    @include('errors.list')
@endif
```

in the sidebar, and the inverse in the form not in the sidebar.